# Understanding how to return a scanner object

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I've been searching online for a solution for days and  yet to find anything so I'm starting to think my understanding is incorrect. I'm writing a command line program that takes in certain parameters and a file name and then manipulates that data based on the parameters entered. I figured out how to read the data in via the Scanner class and manipulating it but what I'm struggling with is, how do I save the data in a scanner class to be used by other methods?

For example terminal input is -w -n sample.txt where -w removes white space, and -n adds number lines. After -w removes the whitespace, I want to reuse the same data and pass it in to the -n method to add number lines.

Code:

```
    public static String Wmethod(Scanner dataRead, Scanner outputData){

        //Reads the data and manipulates it.
        while (dataRead.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = dataRead.nextLine();
            data = data.replaceAll("\\s","");
            data = data.replaceAll("\\t","");
            data = data.replaceAll(" ","");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        dataRead.close();

        //TODO: Need to figure out how to put the string data back into the scanner to be used by other methods. 


        System.out.println("W method triggered");

        return "W method triggered";
    }
```

Comment: Don’t print it, return it—right now you return a hardcoded string that looks more like a status log.

Comment: Right, but do I just do return dataRead and change the return type? If I'm manipulating the data with a string variable, how does the system update the scanner object with the new data?

Comment: I don't think there's much point in passing in the extra `Scanner`. Just accumulate the transformed string in a `StringBuilder` then at the end `return sb.toString()` You can use another `Scanner` from there on

Comment: You wouldn’t “update the scanner object with new data”, you read and transform the data. E.g., read a line, run all appropriate transforms, write the line. The transformers shouldn’t care where the data comes from—transforms just need the data.